# Opening /dev/input/* character device always results in a segfault

Tags: c++, linux, input, stream

I have a C++ program that is supposed to be something of a raw keyboard-and-mouse event handler by reading from a character device file in Linux.

The problem is, whenever I attempt to read the stream by literally ANY I/O function (e.g. getc, fgetc, read, gets, scan, etc...) it will always produce a segfault. I even check to make sure that the file is not NULL, in which case the program throws a regular error.

Here's exactly what my program does:

```
FILE * mouseFile;
FILE * kbdFile; //Definitions for my streams

mouseFile = fopen("/dev/input/mice", "r"); //Open mice stream in readonly

kbdFile = fopen("/dev/input/event5", "r"); //In my case, the keyboard is event 5

/* 
A loop here that uses one of the I/O functions i talked about earlier, and 
then simply prints that to standard output. This is where I assume that  the
segfault happens, because i can open the stream just fine.
*/
```

I would use X or SDL, but i'm planning to eventually port this into NASM assembly or some other very low-level code, and I don't really want to bother with external libraries.

Comment: Please show the actual code that seg faults. In any case, you shouldn't be using those IO functions since the event data is binary not strings. Use `read`.

Comment: Segfault generally means improper use of a pointer. Did you check whether `fopen` returned a non-null pointer? If `mouseFile` is valid, then the problem is that the string you're reading into is an invalid pointer.